# MS Access SQL Query (not VBA) to 3rd Party Database

Tags: ms-access

Looking to do this without using VBA and using MS Access SQL. You know, going to Query Design and then clicking the "SQL" button in the bottom right corner.

I have some users that know basic SQL SELECT queries, but don't know VBA, and want to write their own queries while we are building the front-end for the PostgreSQL database everything is being migrated to. What is the syntax to query an ODBC connection in MS Access SQL (again, not using VBA)?

In a nutshell, database migrated from Access to PostgreSQL, some users know SQL but not VBA, want to do queries that haven't been built into the new front-end yet, looking for the correct syntax in MS Access SQL `FROM [ODBC:postgres].Users` or something. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider either of following. During creation of either, you will be prompted for ODBC DSN/Driver. Two prerequisites are required: MS Access GUI .exe and [Postgres ODBC driver](https://odbc.postgresql.org/):

1. **LINKED TABLES**: link Postgres tables in Access frontend and write queries with Access SQL dialect. Since linked tables are live, all data changes reflect in the Postgres database. Find this option under *External Data* tab and choose the globe icon.
2. **PASS-THRU QUERIES**: create pass-thru queries and write in Postgres SQL dialect. Do note: only single statements are allowed, no multi-step or stored procedures allowed. Find this special query type under *Create* / *Query Design* conditional tab, also a globe icon.